# Creating an Array from a Range in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, range

I'm having a seemingly basic problem but can't find any resources addressing it.

Simply put, I just want to load the contents of a Range of cells (all one column) into an Array.

I am able to accomplish this by means of

```
DirArray = Array(Range("A1"), Range("A2"))
```

But for some reason, I cannot create the array when expressed this way:

```
DirArray = Array(Range("A1:A2"))
```

My real Range is much longer (and may vary in length), so I don't want to have to individually enumerate the cells this way. Can anyone tell me how to properly load a whole Range into an Array?

With the latter code:

```
MsgBox UBound(DirArray, 1)
```

And

```
MsgBox UBound(DirArray)
```

Return 0, whereas with the former they return 1.

Comment: Loop through your range.

Comment: Isn't that less efficient though? I thought surely there was a method or property that would allow the whole range to be loaded into the array at once. Or something with a similar effect, if there's a non-array object type I should be using instead...

Comment: you should be able to just do this. - DirArray = Range("A1:A2")

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Just define the variable as a variant, and make them equal:

```
Dim DirArray As Variant
DirArray = Range("a1:a5").Value
```

No need for the Array command.

Comment: Wow, that is blindingly obvious. I had tried that but not, I think, in conjunction with DirArray(1, 1), which was needed instead of just DirArray(1). Thank you so much!

Comment: But then is that not a Variant and not an array? Is there a memory use difference in this case?

Comment: I realize now that using Variant arrays is one of the only ways to do somethings in Excel.

Comment: This actually creates an array length 5 of arrays of length one of variants.

Comment: Almost. It is recommended to show the array as an array of `Variants`. Declare `Dim DirArray() As Variant` instead.

Comment: @basaltanglia Could you explain the need for DirArray(1,1) in returning values? This seems like a 1D array to me, so DirArray(1) should work.

Comment: @ja72 Recommended by whom? Stuffing an array inside a variant is almost always the better option.

Comment: @ExcelHero - I did a test and both `DirArray As Variant` and `DirArray() As Variant` yield the exact same data structure in memory. So the point is moot.

Comment: @ja perhaps your point is moot... and that's why I brought it to your attention. My point, however, is far from moot. A variant holding the array is far more flexible than a declared array of variants!

Comment: Suppose your range is only one cell. DirArray = Range("a1:a1").Value, DirArray is no longer an array

Comment: @ExcelHero I would like to know in which way it is more flexible and if there is any efficiency loss. Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 77):

If we do it just like this:

```
Dim myArr as Variant
myArr = Range("A1:A10")
```

the new array will be with two dimensions. Which is not always somehow comfortable to work with:

[image]

To get away of the two dimensions, when getting a single column to array, we may use the built-in Excel function “Transpose”. With it, the data becomes in one dimension:

[image]

If we have the data in a row, a single transpose will not do the job. We need to use the Transpose function twice:

[image]

**Note:** As you see from the screenshots, when generated this way, arrays start with 1, not with 0. ***Just be a bit careful.***

**Edit June 2021:**
In newer versions of Excel, the function is: `Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose()`

**Edit February 2024:**
Made a YouTube video, explaining that one:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cGKUdKCSQxk

Comment: God all the times I have done extra unnecessary steps. +1

Comment: Also, `myArr = [transpose(A1:A10)]`

Comment: @Slai - yup, it works as well, but I am having my own rule, to use `[]` only for named ranges, like in the third point here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/35864330/5448626

Comment: To hopefully save others time, newer versions of Excel now have the function as Application.WorksheetFunctions.Transpose()

Comment: @TravelinGuy - no `Application.Transpose` is the late-bound version of `Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose`.

Comment: If range consists of one cell, the Transpose ran twice trick returns a value, no longer an array

Answer (score 35):

Using `Value2` gives a performance benefit.  As per [Charles Williams blog](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/30/text-vs-value-vs-value2-slow-text-and-how-to-avoid-it/)

> Range.Value2  works the same way as Range.Value, except that it does not check the cell format and convert to Date or Currency. And thats probably why its faster than .Value when retrieving numbers.

So

```
DirArray = [a1:a5].Value2
```

### Bonus Reading

- [Range.Value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.value): *Returns or sets a Variant value that represents the value of the specified range.*
- [Range.Value2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.value2): *The only difference between this property and the Value property is that the Value2 property doesn't use the Currency and Date data types.*

Answer (score 7):

This function returns an array regardless of the size of the range.

Ranges will return an array unless the range is only 1 cell and then it returns a single value instead.  This function will turn the single value into an array (1 based, the same as the array's returned by ranges)

This answer improves on previous answers as it will return an array from a range no matter what the size. It is also more efficient that other answers as it will return the array generated by the range if possible.  Works with single dimension and multi-dimensional arrays

The function works by trying to find the upper bounds of the array.  If that fails then it must be a single value so we'll create an array and assign the value to it.

```
Public Function RangeToArray(inputRange As Range) As Variant()
Dim size As Integer
Dim inputValue As Variant, outputArray() As Variant

    ' inputValue will either be an variant array for ranges with more than 1 cell
    ' or a single variant value for range will only 1 cell
    inputValue = inputRange

    On Error Resume Next
    size = UBound(inputValue)

    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        RangeToArray = inputValue
    Else
        On Error GoTo 0
        ReDim outputArray(1 To 1, 1 to 1)
        outputArray(1,1) = inputValue
        RangeToArray = outputArray
    End If

    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

Answer (score 6):

In addition to solutions proposed, and in case you have a 1D range to 1D array, i prefer to process it through a function like below. The reason is simple: If for any reason your range is reduced to 1 element range, as far as i know the command Range().Value will not return a variant array but just a variant and you will not be able to assign a variant variable to a variant array (previously declared).

I had to convert a variable size range to a double array, and when the range was of 1 cell size, i was not able to use a construct like range().value so i proceed with a function like below.

```
Public Function Rng2Array(inputRange As Range) As Double()

    Dim out() As Double    
    ReDim out(inputRange.Columns.Count - 1)

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To inputRange.Columns.Count - 1
        out(i) = inputRange(1, i + 1) 'loop over a range "row"
    Next

    Rng2Array = out  
End Function
```

Comment: Good catch.  But also note if the Range is columnar, you'd need to look at inputRange.Rows.Count, not inputRange.Columns.Count.  You'd also use the counter variable in your assignment statement on the row, not the column.

Answer (score 5):

I'm another vote for iterating through the cells in the range. Unless somebody has found a workaround, my experience trying to assign the range directly to a Variant has been that it works fine (albeit returning a 2-dimensional array when I really only need 1D) *except* if my range has multiple areas, like for example, when I want just the visible cells in a column of a filtered table, or if I have ctrl-selected different blocks of cells on a sheet.

Iterating through all the cells in the range with a for..each loop always produces the results I expect.

```
Public Function RangeToArray(ByRef myRange As Range)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim individualCell As Range
    
    ReDim myArray(myRange.Count - 1)

    For Each individualCell In myRange
        myArray(i) = individualCell.Text         ' or maybe .Value
        i = i + 1
    Next
    RangeToArray = myArray
    
End Function
```

I wanted to add this as a comment to Paolo's answer since it's pretty similar but I am a newbie and don't have enough reputation, so here's another *slightly* different answer.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @Vityata 's answer, below is the function I use to convert a row / column vector in a 1D array:

```
Function convertVecToArr(ByVal rng As Range) As Variant
'convert two dimension array into a one dimension array
    
    Dim arr() As Variant, slicedArr() As Variant
    arr = rng.value   'arr = rng works too (https://bettersolutions.com/excel/cells-ranges/vba-working-with-arrays.htm)
    
    If UBound(arr, 1) > UBound(arr, 2) Then
        slicedArr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arr)
    Else
        slicedArr = Application.WorksheetFunction.index(arr, 1, 0)  'If you set row_num or column_num to 0 (zero), Index returns the array of values for the entire column or row, respectively._
                                                                   'To use values returned as an array, enter the Index function as an array formula in a horizontal range of cells for a row,_
                                                                   'and in a vertical range of cells for a column.
                                                                   'https://usefulgyaan.wordpress.com/2013/06/12/vba-trick-of-the-week-slicing-an-array-without-loop-application-index/
    End If
convertVecToArr = slicedArr
End Function
```

Comment: Index(arr, 1, 0) still returns a 2D array, and if its only one cell, it returns the value, which is no longer an array

Answer (score 0):

Transpose is a great advice.
I have multiple arrays in my app. Some global, some local, some loaded from ranges and some created programatically.

I had numerous problems with dimensioning. Now, with transpose they are all one dimension.

I did have to modify code slightly, because one version runs on Excel 2003 and another (slower) on 2010.

Caution: You will have to Transpose the array again, when saving it to a range.

Answer (score 0):

### Using the shape of the Range

Another approach in creating a function for `ArrayFromRange` would be using the shape and size of the Range to determine how we should structure the array. This way we don't have to load the data into an intermediate array to determine the dimension.

For instance, if the target range is only one cell, then we know we want to return an array with the single value in it `Array(target.value)`.

Below is the complete function that should deal with all cases. Note, this uses the same technique of using the [`Application.Transpose`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.transpose) method to reshape the array.

```vb
' Helper function that returns an array from a range with the
' correct dimensions. This fixes the issue of single values
' not returning as an array, and when a 2 dimension array is returned
' when it only has 1 dimension of data.
'
' @author Robert Todar <robert@roberttodar.com>
Public Function ArrayFromRange(ByVal target As Range) As Variant
    Select Case True
        ' Single cell
        Case target.Cells.Count = 1
            ArrayFromRange = Array(target.Value)
            
        ' Single Row
        Case target.Rows.Count = 1
            ArrayFromRange = Application.Transpose( _
                Application.Transpose(target.Value) _
            )
        
        ' Single Column
        Case target.Columns.Count = 1
            ArrayFromRange = Application.Transpose(target.Value)
            
        ' Multi dimension array
        Case Else
            ArrayFromRange = target.Value
    End Select
End Function
```

### Testing the `ArrayFromRange` function

As a bonus, here are the tests that I ran to check that this function works.

```vb
' @requires {function} ArrayDimensionLength
' @requires {function} ArrayCount
Private Sub testArrayFromRange()
    ' Setup a new workbook/worksheet for
    ' adding testing data
    Dim testWorkbook As Workbook
    Set testWorkbook = Workbooks.Add
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = testWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    
    ' Add sample data for testing.
    ws.Range("A1:A2") = Application.Transpose(Array("A1", "A2"))
    ws.Range("B1:B2") = Application.Transpose(Array("B1", "B2"))
    
    ' This section will run all the tests.
    Dim x As Variant
    
    ' Single cell
    x = ArrayFromRange(ws.Range("A1"))
    Debug.Assert ArrayDimensionLength(x) = 1
    Debug.Assert ArrayCount(x) = 1
    
    ' Single Row
    x = ArrayFromRange(ws.Range("A1:B1"))
    Debug.Assert ArrayDimensionLength(x) = 1
    Debug.Assert ArrayCount(x) = 2
    
    ' Single Column
    x = ArrayFromRange(ws.Range("A1:A2"))
    Debug.Assert ArrayDimensionLength(x) = 1
    Debug.Assert ArrayCount(x) = 2
    
    ' Multi Column
    x = ArrayFromRange(ws.Range("A1:B2"))
    Debug.Assert ArrayDimensionLength(x) = 2
    Debug.Assert ArrayCount(x) = 4
    
    ' Cleanup testing environment
    testWorkbook.Close False
    
    ' Print result
    Debug.Print "testArrayFromRange: PASS"
End Sub
```

#### Helper functions for the tests

In my tests I used two helper functions: `ArrayCount`, and `ArrayDimensionLength`. These are listed below for reference.

```vb
' Returns the length of the dimension of an array
'
' @author Robert Todar <robert@roberttodar.com>
Public Function ArrayDimensionLength(sourceArray As Variant) As Integer
On Error GoTo catch
    Do
        Dim currentDimension As Long
        currentDimension = currentDimension + 1
        
        ' `test` is used to see when the
        ' Ubound throws an error. It is unused
        ' on purpose.
        Dim test As Long
        test = UBound(sourceArray, currentDimension)
    Loop
catch:
    ' Need to subtract one because the last
    ' one errored out.
    ArrayDimensionLength = currentDimension - 1
End Function
```

```vb
' Get count of elements in an array regardless of
' the option base. This Looks purely at the size
' of the array, not the contents within them such as
' empty elements.
'
' @author Robert Todar <robert@roberttodar.com>
' @requires {function} ArrayDimensionLength
Public Function ArrayCount(ByVal sourceArray As Variant) As Long
    Dim dimensions As Long
    dimensions = ArrayDimensionLength(sourceArray)
    
    Select Case dimensions
        Case 0
            ArrayCount = 0
        
        Case 1
            ArrayCount = (UBound(sourceArray, 1) - LBound(sourceArray, 1)) + 1
        
        Case Else
            ' Need to set arrayCount to 1 otherwise the
            ' loop will keep multiplying by zero for each
            ' iteration
            ArrayCount = 1
           
            Dim dimension As Long
            For dimension = 1 To dimensions
                ArrayCount = ArrayCount * _
                    ((UBound(sourceArray, dimension) - LBound(sourceArray, dimension)) + 1)
            Next
    End Select
End Function
```