# Creating an Array from a Variable Range in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I'm looking for a way to create an array from a variable range in VBA. I've seen a similar [posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37689847/creating-an-array-from-a-range-in-vba) but I can not find the way to adjust it to a variable range.

What I have is a Sheet with variable columns and I want store these into an array. So far I have the following code, but it is giving an error when trying to assign the dynamic range (HCRng)

```
Sub TestColumnNames()
Dim ArrayColumns As Variant
Dim HCRng As Range
HCRng = Sheets("HC").Range("A1", Selection.End(xlToRight))
ArrayColumns = HCRng.Value
End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Comment: To assign to any object variable (including a Range variable), you need to use Set. So "Set HCRng = Sheets(..."

Comment: also this will error if the selection is on a different sheet than `HC`, just an FYI.

Comment: You may want to change that line to: `set HCRng = Sheets("HC").Range("A1", Sheets("HC").Range("A1").End(xlToRight))`

Comment: Thanks Scott. That works!!

Comment: To populate `ArrayColumns` you can cut out the middleman: `ArrayColumns = Sheets("HC").Range("A1", Selection.End(xlToRight)).Value`. Unless you plan to do other things with `HCRng`, it isn't needed.