# Excel VBA: How do I assign a range to a variable?

Tags: vba, excel

The current code is as follows:

```
With Sheets(sheetChk)
    a = .Range(chkCell, .Range(Left(chkCell, 1) & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value
End With
```

sheetChk is defined as the desired sheet index.
chkCell is defined as the desired "first cell" in the range.

I am attempting to assign a range to *a*. The problem is that the above code grabs the last cell in the column, entirely. Rather, I want to end at a specific row as I have other data in the same column after the desired range that needs to be ignored. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean but maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37689847/creating-an-array-from-a-range-in-vba) helps or more in detail [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx)

Comment: What is “chkcell”? A Range? If so, what is “Left(chkCell, 1)” supposed to do?

Comment: @DisplayName I'm guessing the OP is using `chkCell` to manually enter the address. The syntax would indicate it's grabbing the first letter for a column address. `Left(chkCell.Value,1)`

Comment: @PGCodeRider you're correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First to assign a range, you need to have a `Set` first.

Example: `Set a = Range("A1")`

Another problem I see is that you're putting a `.value` at the end. That doesn't make sense for a range.

If you want to specify a specific row, then you need to include that in the code instead of using `end(xlUp)`.

Example if it's row 50:

```
With Sheets(sheetChk)
    Set a = .Range(chkCell, .Range(Left(chkCell, 1) & 50).End(xlUp))
End With
```

What you're currently using is finding the bottom row being used, which doesn't sound like you want. If you want to go the other direction (i.e. from the starting cell down until there's an empty cell), you can use this code:

```
With Sheets(sheetChk)
    Set a = .Range(chkCell, .Range(Left(chkCell, 1) & chkCell.Row).End(xlDown))
End With
```

Based on your code, it looks like you might be putting an address in whatever cell `chkCell` is. If you have the row in that cell, and assuming you never exceed column z, then you could use this code to find the row:

```
With Sheets(sheetChk)
    Set a = .Range(chkCell, .Range(Left(chkCell, 1) & Right(chkCell,Len(chkCell)-1))
End With
```

If that doesn't work, you need to figure out some method determine what row to use. Hope that helps.

Comment: This did the trick. I appreciate your input. Sleep wasn't in my favor when I posted, and I now see my foolish mistake.

Comment: I didn't realize the accept button was there. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

```
dim rng as range
set rng = thisworkbook.sheets("sheet1").range("a1:a666")
```