# For Each - Open specified workbooks in array

Tags: excel, vba

I have about 200ish workbooks That I need opened in a dir containing thousands of files. The name of these 200 files have been placed in `Sheet 4 B3:B231`.

**Whenever I run the macro however, I only get the code to work on 4 of these files, 1 of the 4 isn't even mentioned in the specified range.**

```
Dim wb As Workbook, shtDest As Worksheet
Dim MyFile As String
Dim Filepath As String
Dim WoBo As Variant
Dim DirArray As Variant
DirArray = Sheets("Sheet4").Range("B3:B231").Value

Filepath = "C:\"
MyFile = Dir(Filepath)

Set shtDest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

For Each WoBo In DirArray
      'code  
Next WoBo
End Sub
```

I'm quite new to arrays and I don't really understand the For Each line, so I suspect the error to be there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52467171/5448626

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like the following. A For Loop is faster than a For Each for arrays and using Transpose turns it into a one dimensional array to loop over.

```
Dim dirArray()
dirArray = Application.Transpose(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("B3:B231").Value)

For i = LBound(dirArray) To Ubound(dirArray)
    If instr(dirArray(i),"xls") > 0 Then '<== very basic check
        Workbooks.Open(dirArray(i))  '<== should be full filepath of file
        ' Do stuff
    End If
Next
```

Comment: What do you mean with " '<== should be full filepath of file"? Do I simply copy the filepath to this line? If I don't add anything I get the error "sorry we could'nt find filename. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?"

Comment: The cells you are reading in from should contain the full file path to the file I believe  C:\Users\path.....\workbookX.xlsx.

Comment: Did you try that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The files that have to be read are all in the same directory, C:\Users\path...\workbookX.xlsx. Each one of these workbooks is defined in sheet 4 range B3:B231 with just the filename itself. workbook1.xlsx, workbook2.xlsx, etc. .

Comment: You need concatenate the path on the name before passing to workbooks.open

Comment: I've slightly altered the code, based on yours. And got it to work. Thank you.