# Store element from excel into array VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have some data in terms of a column that I want to store into an array using VBA. After storing it, I will reference the element in the array and make a comparison.

```
Dim tRange As Range

Set tRange = wb.Sheets("wbname").Range("A1:A5")
```

Lets say I want to store `column A` with 5 row into the array in VBA. May I know  the way?

Comment: See here for further reading on arrays: https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-array/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
Sub Dave()
    Dim tRange As Range, wb As Workbook, cell As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set tRange = wb.Sheets("wbname").Range("A1:A5")

    ReDim arr(1 To tRange.Count)
    i = 1
    For Each cell In tRange
        arr(i) = cell.Value
        i = i + 1
      Next cell
End Sub
```

**NOTE:**

This technique does not depend on the "shape" of the range.  It will work if the range is a piece of a column, or a piece of a row, or a rectangle of cells, or even a disjoint set of cells.

Comment: Thanks @Gary's Student , your solution works for me but in term of speed, i need to avoid using for loop. Thanks!

Comment: @Dave would you like a non-looping alternative ??

Comment: thanks for the offer bro, I manage to solve it by looking on the other previous existing problem post by others. BTW, thanks again , God bless <3

Answer (score 0):

You can just declare a Variant data type and make it equal to the range.

```
Dim DirArray As Variant
DirArray = Range("a1:a5").Value
```

This was answered in a previous question by @vacip coincidentally for exactly the same range!
[Creating an Array from a Range in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37689847/creating-an-array-from-a-range-in-vba)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have few things to ask

1. How can i reference the element in the array? Like  DirArray(1) to get the first element assume the array start from 1.

2. How can I get the  number of element in the array? As i know if I use range 
  eg:  Dim tRange As Range ,   I can use " tRange.rows.count " to get the total element in the range. Thanks


@Earl_of_Duke

Comment: @dave you can use `DirArray(i)` to reference the i'th element in your array. To get the number of elements you can use `UBound(DirArray)`. I recommend reading through the article I posted in the comments to your question. That will give you a better understanding to your questions.

Comment: @Earl_of_Duke Thanks dude, bless you<3

Comment: @Dean - small correction: as the above datafield array creates a **2-dimensioned** (1-based) array, you get the first element via `DirArray(1,1)`, the second via `DirArray(2,1)` etc. Otherwise in order to get a 1-dim array you'd have to *flatten* data coding `Application.Transpose(Range("A1:A5").Value)` first to be able to get `DirArray(1)` with one index Parameter only. - *Side note:* It's better practice to fully qualify your range references, e.g. using `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheetname").Range("A1:A5").Value`.

Comment: Hi @T.M. Yes! That is what I did, but with ".Value2 ". So when I want to reference the element from the array I will reference it as **DirArray(I,1)** where **I** is the counter for loop. Hope I was correct about it. Thanks btw <3

Comment: @T.M. yes you are correct, thanks for the correction.