# Getting an array of strings from cells in excel - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a program that needs to read an array of values from cells in another worksheet in the same workbook. I am able to read a single value just fine, but when I try to read multiple, I cannot return an array.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
    Dim list() As Variant
    list = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:C2").value
    Debug.Print TypeName(list)
    Debug.Print UBound(list)
    Debug.Print LBound(list)
    Debug.Print TypeName(list(UBound(list)))
```

For which the output is:

```
Variant()
 1 
 1 
Subscript out of range
```

However, If I try it where I expect a single string, instead of an array of strings

```
    Dim value As String
    Let value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Site IDs and CJONs").Range("A2").value
    Debug.Print TypeName(value)
    Debug.Print value
```

for which I get the output

```
String
Expected Value
```

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37689847/creating-an-array-from-a-range-in-vba) I should be able to simply return an array from the range function (example from the answer below), but it doesn't seem to be working for me. What am I doing wrong?

```
    Dim DirArray As Variant
    DirArray = Range("a1:a5").Value
```

Comment: Note that a single cell is a special case, see http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx... and that these are 2D arrays.

Comment: `List` is a 2D array if there is more than one cell, so you need to refer to both.  eg `debug.print list(1,1)`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thanks, that fixed it for me.

Comment: This answer shows how you can use transpose to make it a 1d array. If your range is a row, you need to use transpose twice. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37689847/creating-an-array-from-a-range-in-vba

Answer (score 3):

Although it is not obvious, this:

```
Dim DirArray As Variant
DirArray = Range("a1:a5").Value
```

actually is like:

```
Dim DirArray(1 To 5, 1 To 1) As Variant

DirArray(1, 1) = Range("A1").Value
DirArray(2, 1) = Range("A2").Value
DirArray(3, 1) = Range("A3").Value
DirArray(4, 1) = Range("A4").Value
DirArray(5, 1) = Range("A5").Value
```

Pulling a set of cells into an array usually makes a **2-D** array.

**NOTE:**

If you want to go from array to worksheet cells then, for example:

```
Sub ytrewq()
    Dim DirArray(1 To 5, 1 To 1) As Variant

    DirArray(1, 1) = "Larry"
    DirArray(2, 1) = "Moe"
    DirArray(3, 1) = "Curly"
    DirArray(4, 1) = "Shepp"
    DirArray(5, 1) = "James"

    Range("B9").Resize(5, 1) = DirArray
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I might as well put my comment as an answer:

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()    
Dim list As Variant
    list = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:C2").Value))
    Debug.Print TypeName(list)
    Debug.Print UBound(list)
    Debug.Print LBound(list)
    'Debug.Print UBound(list, 2) Error
    'Debug.Print LBound(list, 2) Error
    Debug.Print TypeName(list(UBound(list)))
    Debug.Print list(UBound(list))
End Sub
```

Gives output:

```
Variant()
 3 
 1 
String
x
```

where C2 contains letter x.

Comment: Thank you! This helped my get it to my expected format