# How to make VBA code run faster when looping through 10,000 cells?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub GMC()  
    strike = 100
    cap = 120
    part = 3.25
    KO = 60

    For i = 1 To 1000
        exp(i) = Worksheets("Speeder premium").Cells(i + 1, 32)
        If exp(i) >= cap Then
            cash = strike + (part * (cap - strike))
        ElseIf exp(i) >= strike And exp(i) < cap Then
            cash = strike + (part * (exp(i) - strike))
        ElseIf exp(i) < strike And exp(i) >= KO Then
            cash = strike
        ElseIf exp(i) < strike And exp(i) < KO Then
            cash = exp(i)
        End If
        
        Worksheets("Speeder premium").Cells(i + 1, 33) = cash
    Next i
End Sub
```

So right now I'm repeating the below code for 1000 repetitions but ideally would like to do so for 10,000. I tried doing this with 10,000 and it is very slow and takes too long to process. How do I make the code faster and more efficient?

Comment: Write to an array.

Comment: Why not just use a formula?

Comment: @SJR meaning? I didn't understand how I should implement the array here.

Comment: load full range in an array, make calculs in the array, then copy back array to range

Comment: There are many examples online.

Comment: @VincentG so once I have the exp array, I should just loop through each value in that array to see if the if conditions are being met? I'm sorry if I misunderstood, I'm just not able to grasp what you mean by the 'range'.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37689847/creating-an-array-from-a-range-in-vba

Comment: @SJR I see thank you for your help. The range method definitely helped. However, the main problem seems to be looping through the `if` conditions and not adding values to the `exp` array. Is there anything that can be done to speed up the check for the if conditions?

Comment: Possibly you could do a lookup or use IFS if you have 365. However in an array it will be lightning fast if you're doing it right!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Using Arrays

- I would encourage you to use `Option Explicit` which will force you to declare all variables which among others, will make the code more readable, unexpected behavior (errors) easier traceable...  It is a little more work, but in the long run, it will surely pay off.

**A Quick Fix**

```
Sub GMC()
    ' Worksheet
    wsName = "Speeder premium"
    fRow = 2
    rCount = 10000
    sCol = 32
    dCol = 33
    ' Data
    Strike = 100
    cap = 120
    part = 3.25
    KO = 60
    ' Define workbook.
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    ' Define Source Range.
    Set rng = wb.Worksheets(wsName).Cells(fRow, sCol).Resize(rCount)
    ' Write values from Source Range to Source Array.
    Source = rng.Value
    ' Define Destination Array.
    ReDim Dest(1 To rCount, 1 To 1)
    ' Loop through rows of Source Array, do the calculation, 
    ' and write the results to Destination Array.
    For i = 1 To rCount
        Curr = Source(i, 1)
        If Curr >= cap Then
            cash = Strike + (part * (cap - Strike))
        ElseIf Curr >= Strike And Curr < cap Then
            cash = Strike + (part * (Curr - Strike))
        ElseIf Curr < Strike And Curr >= KO Then
            cash = Strike
        ElseIf Curr < Strike And Curr < KO Then
            cash = Curr
        End If
        Dest(i, 1) = cash
    Next i
    ' Write values from Destination Array to Destination Range.
    rng.Offset(, dCol - sCol).Value = Dest

End Sub
```

**The Option Explicit Version**

```
Option Explicit

Sub GMC2()
    ' Worksheet
    Const wsName As String = "Speeder premium"
    Const fRow  As Long = 2
    Const rCount As Long = 10000
    Const sCol As Long = 32
    Const dCol As Long = 33
    ' Source
    Const Strike As Long = 100
    Const Cap As Long = 120
    Const Part As Double = 3.25
    Const KO As Long = 60
    ' Define Source Range.
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = wb.Worksheets(wsName).Cells(fRow, sCol).Resize(rCount)
    ' Write values from Source Range to Source Array.
    Dim Source As Variant
    Source = rng.Value
    ' Define Target Array.
    Dim Dest As Variant
    ReDim Dest(1 To rCount, 1 To 1)
    ' Loop through rows of Source Array, do the calculation, and write
    ' the results to Destination Array.
    Dim Curr As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Cash As Double
    For i = 1 To rCount
        Curr = Source(i, 1)
        If Curr >= Cap Then
            Cash = Strike + (Part * (Cap - Strike))
        ElseIf Curr >= Strike And Curr < Cap Then
            Cash = Strike + (Part * (Curr - Strike))
        ElseIf Curr < Strike And Curr >= KO Then
            Cash = Strike
        ElseIf Curr < Strike And Curr < KO Then
            Cash = Curr
        End If
        Dest(i, 1) = Cash
    Next i
    ' Write values from Destination Array to Destination Range.
    rng.Offset(, dCol - sCol).Value = Dest

End Sub
```

**Option Explicit Version with Variable Declarations at the Beginning**

```
Sub GMC3()
    ' Worksheet
    Const wsName As String = "Speeder premium"
    Const fRow  As Long = 2
    Const rCount As Long = 10000
    Const sCol As Long = 32
    Const dCol As Long = 33
    ' Source
    Const Strike As Long = 100
    Const Cap As Long = 120
    Const Part As Double = 3.25
    Const KO As Long = 60
    ' Variables
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim Source As Variant
    Dim Dest As Variant
    Dim Curr As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Cash As Double
    ' Define Source Range.
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set rng = wb.Worksheets(wsName).Cells(fRow, sCol).Resize(rCount)
    ' Write values from Source Range to Source Array.
    Source = rng.Value
    ' Define Target Array.
    ReDim Dest(1 To rCount, 1 To 1)
    ' Loop through rows of Source Array, do the calculation, and write
    ' the results to Destination Array.
    For i = 1 To rCount
        Curr = Source(i, 1)
        If Curr >= Cap Then
            Cash = Strike + (Part * (Cap - Strike))
        ElseIf Curr >= Strike And Curr < Cap Then
            Cash = Strike + (Part * (Curr - Strike))
        ElseIf Curr < Strike And Curr >= KO Then
            Cash = Strike
        ElseIf Curr < Strike And Curr < KO Then
            Cash = Curr
        End If
        Dest(i, 1) = Cash
    Next i
    ' Write values from Destination Array to Destination Range.
    rng.Offset(, dCol - sCol).Value = Dest

End Sub
```

**EDIT**

- Here's a test that might clarify why this code is faster. Use it in a new workbook.

**Test**

```
Option Explicit

Sub SpeedTest()
    
    Const Reps As Long = 1000000
    Dim Data As Variant
    ReDim Data(1 To Reps, 1 To 1)
    Dim Data2 As Variant
    ReDim Data2(1 To Reps, 1 To 1)
    Dim t As Double
  
    t = Timer
    With Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Resize(Reps)
        .Value = Empty
        '.Value = 20000
        '.Value = "This is a test."
        ' This one might take a while (15-20s)(uncomment all four lines):
'        .Offset(, 1).Formula = "=RANDBETWEEN(1,5000)"
'        .Offset(, 1).Value = .Offset(, 1).Value
'        .Formula = "=IF(B1>2500,B1,A1)"
'        .Value = .Value
    End With
    t = Timer - t
    Debug.Print "It took " & t _
        & " seconds to write the data to the worksheet."
    
    t = Timer
    Dim n As Long
    For n = 1 To Reps
        Data(n, 1) = Sheet1.Cells(n, 1).Value
    Next n
    t = Timer - t
    Debug.Print "It took " & t _
        & " seconds to access the worksheet " & Reps _
        & " times to read one cell value."
    Erase Data
    
    t = Timer
    Data2 = Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Resize(Reps).Value
    t = Timer - t
    Debug.Print "It took " & t _
        & " seconds to access the worksheet once to read " & Reps _
        & " values."
    Erase Data2

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. This has worked amazingly well. Could you provide some insight as to exactly why your code has run so much faster than mine?

Comment: This code is accessing the worksheet twice: when reading from it `Source = rng.Value` and when writing to it `rng.Offset(, dCol - sCol).Value = Dest`, while your code would be reading 10000 times from it `exp(i) = Worksheets("Speeder premium").Cells(i + 1, 32)` and writing 10000 to it `Worksheets("Speeder premium").Cells(i + 1, 33) = cash`. You might argue that this code reads 10000 values, but the difference in the time needed between reading 10000 or 1 value is obviously a lot smaller than the differece in the time needed for accessing the worksheet 10000 or once. The same goes for writing.

Comment: I've added a test to the bottom of my post for you to better understand what I wrote in the previous comment.

Comment: Ah, I see. Essentially, the code is going through each row, doing the calculation and then assigning that `cash` value to a new array.

Though I'm not sure what the `resize` method is doing. The internet did not help in clearing my doubts either. Could you do an ELI5? Does the `resize` method directly help in making the code faster?

Comment: From my understanding, `resize` is first selecting  the second row and first 32 columns, and then selecting the rest of the rows until 10,000?

Comment: You have to be more accurate but if you're talking about this line `wb.Worksheets(wsName).Cells(fRow, sCol).Resize(rCount)` then `wb.Worksheets(wsName).Cells(fRow, sCol)` is representing cell `AF2` and [Resize](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize) is resizing to the range `AF2:AF10001`. It is only one 2D Array which you could describe as a worksheet range in memory, so when looping through it you manage it similarly to looping through a range in a worksheet only it's much faster. Similarly to cells in a range, you access its elements with e.g. Data(1,1), ...