# VBA For Loop - Adding certain input to a cell if row contains characters?

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, multiple-columns

EDIT: Here I have updated Code that @k1dfr0std was kind enough to help me with:

```
Dim lrow As Long
Dim lLastRow As Long
'This is where the error is happening
lLastRow = ThisWorkbook.Range(Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
Dim i As Long 'Using Long in case there are 1000's of Rows being used. . .
'If there are 1000's and 1000's of rows, you may want to reference

For lrow = 19 To lLastRow
    'Using "With" statement here to prevent the need to retype all of the jargon
    'at the beginning of each line ("ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(lRow,1)).
    With ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(lrow, 1))
    
    'Using the "Like" operator here allows us to use Wildcards in our search Vs the "Instr" structure.
    If .Value Like "*CON*" Then
        'Range does not have to be set, nor does it have to be selected.
        'The Range is actually defined by the "With" statement, so we only need to specify the .Value property
        '.Offset will always modify the offset of the range specified.
        'We are using the lRow determined by the loop, and Column "A" referenced as "1"
        'The offset is the same Row "0" and 2 columns to the left (Assuming you want to SKIP Column B since you always delete it.
        .Offset(0, 8).Value = i
        'Incrementing i ONLY when "CON" is found
        i = 22
    Else
        .Offset(0, 2).Value = "17"
    
    End If

Next lrow

End Sub
```

I am now getting this error: Compile error:

Method or data member not found and "Range" is highlighted in row 3. I am not sure how to tackle this.

I am working with VBA and trying to add to a for loop code macro I have. The code I have deletes a column, has a for loop inserting a row if a cell is bold (this is what I would like to add to, or add another loop), and then adds a specific descriptor. Here is my code:

```
Range("B:B").Delete

Dim lRow As Long
Dim lLastRow As Long
lLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For lRow = lLastRow To 19 Step -1
    If Cells(lRow, "A").Font.Bold = True Then
        Cells(lRow, "A").EntireRow.Insert     
    End If
Next lRow

Rows("19:19").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
Range("B20").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Configuration Name"
Range("C20").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[1]C[-1]"
Range("D20").Select
```

My hope is to have the loop go through the same column as the bold, but if matches certain parameters, then it will add a value to a cell in its respective row.

For example, if a column contains 'apple', I want to direct it to another column and have it show 'orange'.

Comment: Welcome, Aaron! Can you clarify what you mean "show 'orange'"?  Is this to say "I want another cell in a separate column to have the word "orange" displayed, or do you want the cell to be orange in color?  This matters :).  Second Question, is the other column _always_ going to be the same column, or does the column change depending on the cell and the column you are currently searching?  It looks like your for loop always searches Column A:A.

Comment: Hi @k1dfr0std, thanks for replying and the warm welcome! It will be another cell in another column showing the same value as long as it matches a certain text in column A. So, what I actually need is if for example, in column A it includes the characters "CON" then I want a numerical value to generate in a separate column. The generated values will always be in that column so don't have to worry about jumping to different columns. 
It essentially is, if column A contains a certain text then I want a numerical value to show up in another column (same row). Sorry if it is still confusing!!!

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). Have a look at the `Range.Offset` method too.

Comment: @Aaron Meyer, I've given a good shot at answering for you - if the answer below is not what you are looking for, please let me know, and add a little more clarifications to the question, including what your current code is attempting to do.

Comment: @Aaron Meyer, did you find what you were looking for?

Comment: @k1dfr0std Hi There. work has been crazy. About to dive into this right now, I really appreciate you helping. I will hopefully be able to see if this will implement by the end of the day. Again, thank you so much for helping.

Comment: [![Error][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3cOW.png

Getting this error for some reason

Comment: [![Error][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3cOW.png
Getting this error

Tried to alter the code to show "22" else "17" because that is what I am trying to do for this document. It is rather confusing if you are on the outside but I am setting this up for Salesforce Ingestion

Comment: @Aaron Meyer, Thank you for posting the updated code, and please, please forgive me - I normally use my work PC for all of my coding, so I could not see the error codes (they have imgur restricted) - I checked this on my mobile and have found at least _one part_ of the issue. . .   I have updated both your code and my code w/ the proper use of the `.Range` property.  I missed placing an actual `SHEET` to be used.  Otherwise - as long as you don't care what `i` equals, your code should then work.  You'll have to substitute the sheet name yourselfe

Comment: @k1dfr0std No, thank you! However, if I have to update the sheet name, does that mean it is restricted to just 1 particular sheet? My hope is to use these across my Personal Workbook

Comment: I have updated my answer to include another For loop to iterate through each sheet.  This is not the only method to iterate through your sheets - you could use a `For Each` method, but the `For Each` method will "randomly" go through the sheets - if you want to go through your sheets in sequential order, the method I gave is needed.  If you wanted to go backwards, then you would use: `For j = Thisworkbook.Sheets().Count to 1 Step -1`

Comment: Hello Aaron, have you found what you needed for your project?

Answer (score 1):

After more conversation, I think what you are after is as follows.

As @Pᴇʜ mentioned, it's beneficial to get out of the habit of using `.Select` for everything you do - it's messy, unnecessary and can cause more grief in the long run. . . Unfortunately this often given as artifacts from recording a macro in Excel.

If you do not want to restrict things to a single sheet, but rather, you want to include *all sheets* and each sheet has the *same condition* you are looking for, then the modified code below should work for your needs.

In addition, if you do not perform *any* calculations to "i" you could set `i` to equal whatever you want outside of the for loop.  I also noticed you are changing the value 8 columns over if the value you need is found, and 2 columns over if it is not found - I'll incorporate this into my code.

```vb
  Sub loopinThruRows_for_CON()
    Dim lrow as Long
    Dim lLastRow As Long
    'Fixed the line below here - forgive me - '.Range' has to be qualified by a sheet.
    lLastRow = Thisworkbook.Sheets("YourSheetName").Range(Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    
    'Leaving this line in for posterity
    'Dim i as Long 'Using Long in case there are 1000's of Rows being used. . .
    
    'The following line will create variable "i" as an integer and assign the value of 22.
    Const i as integer = 22
    Dim j as Integer 'Using integer for now assuming you have only a hundred sheets or so
    'If there are 1000's and 1000's of rows, you may want to reference the link
      'I provided below. . .
    
    For j = 1 to ThisWorkbook.Sheets().Count
      'This line will activate the 1st sheet, then go through however
      'many sheets you have in the whole workbook.
      'If you need to filter a sheet so it does -NOT- get processed,
      'use an If/Then struct to check the appropriate name.
      'This prevents the "ActiveSheet" portion from doing the work on the
      'Sheet over and over again.
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets(j).Activate

      For lRow = 19 To lLastRow
          'Using "With" statement here to prevent the need to retype all of the jargon 
          'at the beginning of each line ("ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(lRow,1)).
          With ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(lRow,1))
        
          'Using the "Like" operator here allows us to use Wildcards in our search Vs the "Instr" structure.
          If .Value Like "*CON*" Then
              'We are using the lRow determined by the loop, and Column "A" referenced as "1"
              'The offset is the same Row "0" and 8 columns to the right 
              'Use of negative numbers will go the opposite directions.
              .Offset(0,8).Value = i
          
          Else
              .Offset(0,2).Value = "-"
        
          End If
    
      Next lRow

    Next j
    
  End Sub
```

As an aside - if you are dealing with 1000's of rows, it may be more beneficial to put the data into an *Array* instead of iterating through the 1000's of rows, as this can be much faster than trying to manipulate the data inside the cells first.  Reference [this StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37689847/creating-an-array-from-a-range-in-vba) article.

Comment: [![Error][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3cOW.png

Comment: I have updated my code above to reflect the proper way to use `.Range` method - it must be qualified by the Sheet in use.