# want to convert formula to vba array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I want to change the formula to vba array so that it is faster and if using the formula becomes slow for that many records then I have to sort the date in the source sheet. Is there a recommendation that's best?
Thanks
jack

```
'sheet "MASTER" from B2
=LOOKUP(9^9,SOURCE!$B$2:$B$10/(SOURCE!$A$2:$A$10=A2),SOURCE!$B$2:$B$10)
'sheet "MASTER" from C2
=LOOKUP(9^9,SOURCE!$B$2:$B$10/(SOURCE!$A$2:$A$10=A2),SOURCE!$C$2:$C$10)
Sub formulalookup()
        Dim V
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Sheets("MASTER").Range("b2:b" & Sheets("MASTER").UsedRange.Rows.Count)
       .Formula = "=LOOKUP(9^9,SOURCE!$B$2:$B$10/(SOURCE!$A$2:$A$10=A2),SOURCE!$B$2:$B$10)"
        V = .Value
       .Value2 = V
    End With
     With Sheets("MASTER").Range("c2:c" & Sheets("MASTER").UsedRange.Rows.Count)
       .Formula = "=LOOKUP(9^9,SOURCE!$B$2:$B$10/(SOURCE!$A$2:$A$10=A2),SOURCE!$C$2:$C$10)"
        V = .Value
       .Value2 = V
    End With
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

SHEET MASTER

[image]

SHEET SOURCE

[image]

Comment: @braX , I update the vba code but I want the vba array code so that it becomes faster and also before the process is done then first sort the date in the source sheet

Comment: You can [take date into array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37689847/creating-an-array-from-a-range-in-vba/52467171) and then [sort the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152319/vba-array-sort-function)

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns , thanks to your reply, can you answer in response from you changing my vba code or formula into vba array