# Concatenate values of more cells in a single variable in vba

Tags: excel, vba, concatenation

I have an excel file with four columns: name, surname, address, area.
There are a lot of rows.
Is there a way to concatenate all the values of every single row in a variable, using vba?

I need a variable that should contain something like this:

(name1, surname1, address1, area1); (name2, surname2, address2, area2); (name3, surname3, address3, area3)...

Comment: [is this what you're looking for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37689847/creating-an-array-from-a-range-in-vba)

Comment: What do you plan to do with this variable?

Comment: Just a single string variable? Where each value is concatenated?

Comment: @BigBen I want to write a kind of query, more or less. In every row I have the values, so I'm trying to take the values and write something like "Insert values (values1, values2, values3...)" etc.

Comment: Use `&` to concatenate? Or maybe [`Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/join-function)? Hopefully you're not designing something vulnerable to SQL injection btw...

Comment: Hard to tell what exactly you after, but a whole bunch of `Replace()` functions could get you places? `Replace("(" & Mid(Replace(Replace(Application.ArrayToText([A1:D3], 1), Chr(34), ""), ";", ");("), 2), "}", ")")` where your dummy data was in `A1:D3`? Much better solutions out there, with loops etc. But it's best if you have a go at it yourself and report back any issues code-wise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answers, suggestions, ideas and hints. I am sorry if my question was not so clear, all the solutions you added were perfect and extremely elegant.

In the end I found a way - a dumber way in comparison to all the things you wrote - and I solved with a for statement.

I did like this:

```
totRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

 For i = 1 To totRow

    name = Cells(i, 1)
    surname = Cells(i, 2)
    address = Cells(i, 3)
    area = Cells(i, 4)

    Example = Example & "(" & name & ", " &  surname & ", " & address & ", " & area & "); "
    
 Next i

Range("E1").Value = Example
```

It works (it does what I wanted to do), but I noticed a little limit: if the rows are a lot I can't keep the whole text in the variable.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the following data in your worksheet

[image]

Then the following code will read the data into an array …

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Example()
    
    Dim RangeData() As Variant  ' declare an array
    
    RangeData = Range("A1:D5").Value2  ' read data into array
    
End Sub
```

… with the following structure:

[image]

---

Alternatively you can do something like

```
Public Sub Example()   
    Dim DataRange As Range
    Set DataRange = Range("A2:D5")
    
    Dim RetVal As String
    
    Dim Row As Range
    For Each Row In DataRange.Rows
        RetVal = RetVal & "(" & Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Row.Value2)), ",") & "); "
    Next Row

    Debug.Print RetVal
End Sub
```

To get this output:

```
(name1, surname1, address1, area1); (name2, surname2, address2, area2); (name3, surname3, address3, area3); (name4, surname4, address4, area4);
```

Comment: I considered the array, because basically is near to what I need... But is there a way to write the result like a sort of list that shows all the values of the cells of the range?

Comment: @ZeMatteis See my edit for an alternative solution.

Comment: If you dispose of Excel vers. MS365 you might also use `Evaluate("ArrayToText(A2:D5, 1)")` (arg. 1 = strict) resulting in the following output string: `{"name1","surname1","address1","area1";"name2","surname2","address2","area2";"name3","surname3","address3","area3";"name4","surname4","address4","area4"}` @Pᴇʜ
`

Answer (score 2):

> .. is there a way to write the result like a *sort of list* that shows all the values of the cells of the range?

Yes, there is. In addition to PEH's valid answers and disposing of Excel version MS365 you might also use

```
    Dim s as String
    s = Evaluate("ArrayToText(A2:D5, 1)") ' arg. value 1 representing strict format
```

resulting in the following output string:

```
{"name1","surname1","address1","area1";"name2","surname2","address2","area2";"name3","surname3","address3","area3";"name4","surname4","address4","area4"}
```

**Syntax**

> ARRAYTOTEXT(array, [format])

The ARRAYTOTEXT function returns an array of text values from any specified range. It passes text values unchanged, and converts non-text values to text.

The *format* argument has two values, `0` (concise default format) and `1` (strict format to be used here to distinguish different rows, too):

**Strict format**, i.e. value **`1`** includes escape characters and row delimiters. Generates a string that can be parsed when entered into the formula bar. Encapsulates returned strings in quotes except for Booleans, Numbers and Errors.

Comment: Isn't there a `WorksheetFunction` for `ArrayToText` so you don't need to use `Evaluate`? Not familiar with MS365. Would be nicer to handle in VBA.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, yes there is. See the comment section underneath OP's question.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ You can use either the `WorksheetFunction` or late bound `Application.ArrayToText` as alternative to evaluation. Note that a tabular formula entry (e.g. `"."` for Germany) would use possibly different row list separators compared to any of the above VBA solutions using `","` within the row groups.