# How do I assign a range and a 1d array to a 2d variant array?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, range, variant

I'm working on a particular problem wherein I have to read multiple columns from a "sheet" in "file". These columns are to be temporarily stored in a "fileArray" and after some operations, transferred to a "masterFile".

Basically, the range has around 40k values for each column which I want to assign to fileArray(1 to 4)

I'm getting a Subscript out of range error whenever I try to assign values to the fileArray.

```vb
                ReDim fileArray(1 To 4, 1 To fileLastRow - 1)
                Dim arr As Variant
                ' Copy all relevant columns from sheet
                arr = Flatten(sheet.Range(sheet.Cells(2, fileKeyColumn), sheet.Cells(fileLastRow, fileKeyColumn)))
                
                fileArray(1) = arr ' Keep getting subscript out range errors here
                AssignVal fileArray, 1, sheet.Range(sheet.Cells(2, fileKeyColumn), sheet.Cells(fileLastRow, fileKeyColumn))
                If fileTF1Column <> 0 Then fileArray(2) = Flatten(sheet.Range(Cells(2, fileTF1Column), Cells(fileLastRow, fileTF1Column)).value)
                If fileTF2Column <> 0 Then fileArray(3) = Flatten(sheet.Range(Cells(2, fileTF2Column), Cells(fileLastRow, fileTF2Column)).value)
                If fileTF3Column <> 0 Then fileArray(4) = Flatten(sheet.Range(Cells(2, fileTF3Column), Cells(fileLastRow, fileTF3Column)).value)
```

I tried assigning the value directly as
`fileArray(1) = sheet.Range(sheet.Cells(2, fileKeyColumn), sheet.Cells(fileLastRow, fileKeyColumn))`

and

`fileArray(1) = sheet.Range(sheet.Cells(2, fileKeyColumn), sheet.Cells(fileLastRow, fileKeyColumn)).value`

I also tried using Set statement.

When that didn't work, I adapted a Flatten function from a post I found on Stack Overflow to convert range into a 1-d array. I tried assigning it directly to "fileArray(1)" and via a temporary variable "arr".

I even tried creating an AssignVal subroutine to loop through the range and assign value to the Array.

So far, nothing seems to work and my deadline is fast approaching. I'm unable to understand what I'm doing wrong. Can someone help me with this? Also please explain the logic so I can figure it out for myself next time. Thanks!

```vb
Public Function Flatten(inputRange As Range) As Variant()
    'Adapted from code found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37689847/creating-an-array-from-a-range-in-vba
    
    Dim out() As Variant
    ReDim out(1 To inputRange.Rows.count)

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To inputRange.Rows.count
        out(i) = inputRange(i, 1) 'loop over a range "row"
    Next

    Flatten = out
End Function
```

```vb
Public Sub AssignVal(ByRef inputVar() As Variant, ByVal index As Integer, ByVal inputRange As Range)
    'Adapted from code found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37689847/creating-an-array-from-a-range-in-vba
    
    Dim i As Long
    
    If UBound(inputVar, 2) = inputRange.Rows.count Then
    
    For i = 1 To inputRange.Rows.count
        Set inputVar(index)(i) = inputRange(i, 1).value 'loop over a range "row"
    Next
    
    End If

End Sub
```

EDIT:

I found out that I was referencing the array like a dictionary in AssignVal which was causing the problem. The fixed code is here in case someone else has a similar problem. I'm keeping this question open in hopes of finding a more elegant answer.

```vb
                ReDim fileArray(1 To 4, 1 To fileLastRow - 1)
                
                ' Copy all relevant columns from sheet
                
                With sheet
                    AssignVal fileArray, 1, Flatten(.Range(.Cells(2, fileKeyColumn), .Cells(fileLastRow, fileKeyColumn)))
                    If fileTF1Column <> 0 Then AssignVal fileArray, 2, Flatten(.Range(.Cells(2, fileTF1Column), .Cells(fileLastRow, fileTF1Column)))
                    If fileTF2Column <> 0 Then AssignVal fileArray, 3, Flatten(.Range(.Cells(2, fileTF2Column), .Cells(fileLastRow, fileTF2Column)))
                    If fileTF3Column <> 0 Then AssignVal fileArray, 4, Flatten(.Range(.Cells(2, fileTF3Column), .Cells(fileLastRow, fileTF3Column)))
                End With
```

The final procedures used:

```vb
Public Function Flatten(inputRange As Range) As Variant()
    'Adapted from code found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37689847/creating-an-array-from-a-range-in-vba
    
    Dim out() As Variant
    ReDim out(1 To inputRange.Rows.count)

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To inputRange.Rows.count
        out(i) = inputRange(i, 1) 'loop over a range "row"
    Next

    Flatten = out
End Function

Public Sub AssignVal(ByRef inputVar() As Variant, ByVal index As Integer, ByRef inputVarArr() As Variant)
    'Adapted from code found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37689847/creating-an-array-from-a-range-in-vba
    
    Dim i As Long
    
    If UBound(inputVar, 2) = UBound(inputVarArr) Then
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(inputVar, 2)
         inputVar(index, i) = inputVarArr(i) 'loop over a range "row"
    Next
    
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You cannot set a whole dimension with one command in VBA. You need to iterate through it by items.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Try `ReDim fileArray(1 To 4)`.

Comment: @Blackcat, I'm trying to iterate through it using the AssignVal sub, but that doesn't seem to work either

Comment: @MGonet, I am trying to read 4 columns of data skipping the header row. Hence, the `Redim fileArray (1 to 4, 1 to lastRow-1)` statement

Comment: And what will be next? You can have array of arrays, but you cannot populate individual columns at once when you declare 2D array.

Comment: Try to change to `Set inputVar(index,i) = inputRange(i, 1).value`

Comment: @MGonet, next I will be reading the primary key into masterArray(1), then rearrange the latter 3 columns using 2 for loops 
```
for i = 1 to masterLastRow-1
   for j = 1 to fileLastRow-1
        if masterArray(1,i) = fileArray (1,j) then
           masterArray(2,i) = fileArray (2,j)
           ' same for 3 & 4
           exit for
       end if
   next
next

Comment: You have used the Excel tab.  Why are you not importing the file into excel as a csv and then getting the range in one go from the reulting sheet.

Comment: Thanks @Blackcat. I just came back to say that this was the issue. I was also referencing a dictionary in my code and my brain just combined both.
I found a way to use AssignVal and Flatten to solve the issue, in case someone else has the same problem. I'll still keep this question open, in case someone has a better answer.

Comment: @freeflow, the file is not a csv file. Also, in this case, the final output would still be the same range object which I need to manipulate using arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your solution the function `Flatten` is unnecessary. You need only to redefine `AssignVal` a bit.

```
Public Sub AssignVal(ByRef inputVar() As Variant, ByVal index As Integer, ByVal inputRange As Range)
    'Adapted from code found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37689847/creating-an-array-from-a-range-in-vba
    Dim i As Long
    If UBound(inputVar, 2) = inputRange.Rows.Count Then
        For i = 1 To inputRange.Rows.Count
            inputVar(index, i) = inputRange(i, 1).Value 'loop over a range "row"
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

But still you can avoid even this one loop if you accept 2-level structure of your array. Here is an example.

```
Sub TestArray()
   Dim fileArray()
   ReDim fileArray(1 To 2)
   Dim sheet As Worksheet
   Set sheet = ActiveSheet
   Const fileKeyColumn1 = 5
   Const fileKeyColumn2 = 8
   Const fileLastRow = 10
   fileArray(1) = sheet.Range(sheet.Cells(2, fileKeyColumn1), sheet.Cells(fileLastRow, fileKeyColumn1)).Value
   fileArray(2) = sheet.Range(sheet.Cells(2, fileKeyColumn2), sheet.Cells(fileLastRow, fileKeyColumn2)).Value
   Debug.Print fileArray(1)(3, 1)
   Debug.Print fileArray(2)(5, 1)
End Sub
```

[image: Two_columns]

Comment: I'm getting a Type mismatch error when I attempt to iterate using the above logic.
`If masterArray(1)(i, 1) = fileArray(1)(j, 1) Then masterArray(2)(i, 1) = fileArray(2)(j, 1)`
The If condition above gets satisfied but when copying the value, it throws the error. Any thoughts?

Comment: Just realized that masterArray(2), (3) and (4) are simply empty. Any way to initialize them with dimensions of masterArray(1)?

Comment: `Dim MasterArray():   MasterArray = fileArray`